# Recursive logic in shell scripts

Tags: unix

Here is a problem that i need solution for:

Say file A contains names of files B,C,D. And file B contains file names E,F,G etc. File C contains names of files H,I,J and so on......

I have to parse the files starting from A ,and copy the files mentioned in A to dir DIR. I wanna do the same parsing on all the child files B,C,D and get their child files into my dir DIR. This should go on until i reach the last file say Z which doesn't contain any other file names.

How do i do that?

I wanna do the whole thing in a single script and any further optimization would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the files contain other data than file names more parsing could be necessary.

```
DIR="$HOME/DIR"
startfile="a"
counter=0

copy_to_dir ()
{
  while read line ; do
    if [ -f "$line"  ] ; then
      cp "$line" "$2" && ((counter++))
      copy_to_dir "$line" "$2"                  # recurse
    fi
  done < "$1"
} # ----------  end of function copy_to_dir  ----------

if [ -f "$startfile" -a -d "$DIR" ] ; then
  copy_to_dir "$startfile" "$DIR"                        # start copying
fi

printf "'%s' : %d files copied to '%s'\n" "$0" $counter "$DIR"
```

Comment: yeah, there's a bit of parsing to be done. I do the parsing logic and keep the file names in temp_A for A and so on....could u please change the code to reflect that?

Comment: i tried the logic , but the code's throwing up the following message:  "recursion too deep"